# What are the vegetables we can feed a two years old baby?

Tags: feeding

My daughter is two years old. So for we feed her only smashed rice, Dhal, Biscuits and milk.

There after we decided to give all vegetables doctors gave us green light also. What are the vegetable we can give to a two years old baby?

Comment: I removed the part about whether a particular gourd and pumpkin are the same thing -- we don't really do vegetable identification on here (perhaps [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?) -- the rest of the Question seems fine, though!

Comment: Certain there's a dupe - but can't find it right now

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to Baby Center, that I used a lot when my daughter was younger.  It only goes up to 12 months, but if you look through the different ages it lists vegetables suitable for that child's age.  So since your baby is now 2, she should be ready for all vegetables listed on this site.

http://www.babycenter.com/0_age-by-age-guide-to-feeding-your-baby_1400680.bc

Just remember to mash or chop all vegetables up into small easily swallowed pieces.  I'd also suggest the veggies be cooked, so that they're softer and harder to choke on.  Also since they don't have very many teeth to use to chew yet, the softer cooked veggies are much easier for them to mush up in their mouths.

Also it's always a good idea to introduce only 1-2 different foods at a time just in case of any allergies.

Answer (score 4):

Don't sweat it.

2 year old: she can eat almost anything, as long as it does not have the potential to choke her. My kids ate beans, fish, avocado, nuts, chocolate, broccoli, kale, carrots, potatles, cauliflower, apples, bananas, pears, apricots, etc, etc, etc by the time they were 2.